# how to do For loop to plot categorical box plot?

Tags: python, for-loop, boxplot

so I have a dataframe called `'houseCatSale'` and it has a variables that are categorical and I want to do a box plot with `'SalePrice'` which is numerical.

I tried this code but it keeps saying that it could not recognise `houseCatsale[i]`

```
f,axes = plt.subplots(4,1, figsize = (24,12))
colours = ["r","g","c","m"]

count =0 
for i in houseCatsale:
    sb.boxplot(x = 'houseCatsale[i]', y = 'SalePrice', data = houseCatsale)
    count+=1
```

Comment: I don't see `houseCatdata` anywhere in your example. When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`). Welcome to Stackoverflow - please read [mre], [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: sorry I meant houseCatsale. I want to do a box plot for each variable in houseCatsale with SalePrice

Comment: You would simply use the column name of the categorical variable in `x`. Here is an example:https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html. Also, please post the head() of the housecatsale data so that it would be easier to replicate the exception

Comment: Have you looked through any of the results when searching with `python pandas categorical boxplot loop site stackoverflow.com` ? There is likely an answer in there.

Comment: yes I have looked through but it is different from what I want. I can seem to get the for loop to read my variables in houseCatsale